# Finding a path of recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

Hello everyone I have a small problem and I feel a little bit stuck. I manage to get the object that I want, but I don't know how to return the path to that object (how I found it). My code looks like this at the moment:

P.S what I mean by path: every single item has it's name and id. I manage to find an object with id (which I give when call for recursion) and when I find it, I need to create string and add all of it's parents names to it and return it.

```
protected void FindPath(int depth, int id, InventLocationViewModel currentLocation)
    {
        if (depth < 0)
            return;

        if (currentLocation.Id == id)
        {
            selectedLocation = currentLocation;
            return;
        }

        foreach (var child in currentLocation.ChildInventLocations)
        {
            FindPath(depth - 1, id, child);
        }
    }

    protected void SelectedLocation(RecursiveSelectObject args)
    {
        currentLocation = locations.InventLocations.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == locationId.Value);

        FindPath(args.Level, args.Id, currentLocation);

        if (selectedLocation.Id == args.Id)
        {

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what is "selectedLocation"? what is "RecursiveSelectObject"? the element you're looking for is a leaf? is the root? neither? from where node to which node do you want the path? This question code lacks of one point of the route. Or I don't see it.

Comment: selectedLocation - object that I want to return from it. currentLocation - head (the top object). And every single object has Children objects. And yeas, I'm looking for a leaf. For example I know that this item is on depth - 3, and it's id is 50. So My recursion won't go deeper that 3 layers into itself and if I find that object I will do "selectedLocation = currentLocation" and return this object path.

Comment: Instead of having `FindPath` be a void function, have it return a string - the path of the current object. At the bottom of the tree the only data that an individual node knows about its path is its own name, so they would simply return `id.ToString()`. Higher up in the tree, when you iterate over its children, you know their paths by combining the parent path with the child path: `id.ToString() + " - " + FindPath(...)`. This is a standard way of using recursion (combining small return results into larger results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what you want to keep on the way out:

```
protected List<InventLocationViewModel> FindPath(int id, InventLocationViewModel currentLocation)
{
    if (currentLocation.Id == id)
    {
        return new List<InventLocationViewModel> {currentLocation};
    }

    foreach (var child in currentLocation.ChildInventLocations)
    {
        var result = FindPath(id, child);
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Add(currentLocation);
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, look at your picture. Recursion is about how you "see" the problem: each box is the top/root of a tree, even the bottom ones. And then: can I solve it right here on the top node? Yes: done, No: repeat the process for all my children.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid recursiveness and return the tree path of every node with this simple code

Something like this

```
public IEnumerable<InventLocationViewModel> GetPathToId(int findingId, int maxDepth, InventLocationViewModel rootLocation)
{
    if (rootLocation is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rootLocation));
    if (findingId == rootLocation.Id) //same location
        return Enumerable.Repeat(rootLocation, 1);

    var stack = new Stack<(InventLocationViewModel, int)>(); //we use a tuple for keep the record of the depth
    var visitedPoints = new HashSet<InventLocationViewModel>() { rootLocation };

    stack.Push((rootLocation, 0)); //we put the root

    while (stack.TryPop(out var (currentSearchLocation, depth)))
    { //we take the bottom most recent object

        if (currentSearchLocation?.Id == findingId)
        {
            //this is the path from the root to the leaf WITHOUT THE LEAF
            //return stack.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);
            
            //re-inject the currentSearchLocation if needed;
            stack.Push((currentSearchLocation, depth));
            return stack.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);
        }
        if (depth >= maxDepth)
            continue;
        foreach (var inventLocation in currentSearchLocation.ChildLocations ?? Enumerable.Empty<InventLocationViewModel>()) //we
        {
            if (!visitedPoints.Contains(inventLocation))
            {
                visitedPoints.Add(inventLocation);
                stack.Push((inventLocation, depth+1));

            }
        }
    }
    return null; //not found;
}
```

Edit: there is one bug with tree depth check, I'm fixing it.

Edit3: max depth constraint fixed.

Comment: Yep, I'm debuging it now, trying to understand what's happening. I can see that I will have some homework to do...

Comment: My fast advice is "remove max depth constraint", unless the tree is so unbalanced or is so big, the performance gaining is not worthy.

Comment: I will keep this in mind without the depth. I'm creating a weird recursive component. So I will check which runs faster with or without the depth (recursion or stack). Thank you very much

Comment: @PovilasDirse The difference is not usually in performance, but about ensuring you don't get a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: True! My bad not explaining it. I didn't think it.